How to make it more optimal?
Recently I encountered a problem like this : You are given an array $a$ consisting of includes $n$ elements integer values . Define $S$ and $T$ as follows for a subarray in the range $[i;j]$ where $(1≤i≤j≤n)$
$S$ is the sum of the elements in the subarray $[i;j]$
$T$ is the sum of the squares of the elements in the subarray $[i;j]$.
You need to maximize the value of $P$, where $P$ is given by: $P=S^{2}−T$
With the limit $n \leq 10^{5}$ I have difficulty solving the problem within the $2s$ limit with $O(n^{2})$ complexity I'm completely TLE for this problem .I'm curious if there is any formula or mathematical method to solve this problem.. Hope everyone can help me solve this problem or give me some suggestions for ideas. Thanks folks so much.

What are the elements of $a$? Integers, floating-point numbers? Can they be negative? (If not, the answer is trivial!) Perhaps you could post a link to the original problem.

I don't know much about algorithms and I don't what 2s or TLE mean. As TonyK says, if the numbers are all positive the problem is trivial ($i=1,j=n$). If we have reason to believe there may be not too many negatives, then the following may help speed things up relative to the naive approach. Note that $P(i,j+1)=P(i,j)+2a_{j+1}\sum_{k=i}^ja_k$. So if $a_{j+1}>0$ then we know $P(i,j+1)>P(i,j)$ without calculating anything. We can continue until we find a negative $a$ at which point we recalculate. In this way we may be able to find the biggest $P$ without doing too many calculations.

PS It's a slightly odd question. I would think that $P=\frac{1}{j-i+1}S^2 - T $ would be more natural.

@TonyK Sorry for missing the title, the elements are integer values ​​in the range $[-10^{4};10^{4}]$

@Blitzer TLE is a time limit error, it talks about algorithm optimization

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

@provip Can you post a link to the problem? Is it from a recent contest?

@Blitzer: Even if $a_{j+1}>0$, we don't know that $P(i,j+1)>P(i,j)$, because $\sum_{k=i}^ja_k$ might be negative (or zero).

@RobPratt: This is a little more complicated than the maximum subarray problem.
